# E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a docker-compose.yml file to run some protractor tests that are stored in a public repo. There are several containers created in the yml file:

- shared_repo: where tests are cloned.
- selenium-hub: container with a selenium image.
- chrome: container with a selenium/node-chrome-debug.
- protractor: container with a node:12.14 image

Docker-compose file is:

```
version: '2.4'
services:

  shared_repo:
    image: library/postgres:13.2-alpine
    container_name: shared_repo
    command: bash -c "apk add git && sleep 5s && git clone -b main https://github.com/AlfredoBazo/opwDocker.git && mv /opwDocker /shared_repository && echo "TEST" && sleep 100s"
    ports:
    - 1603:1603
    volumes:
    - shared_repository:/e2e-shared

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
    - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    container_name: chrome
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
    - "5900:5900"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=chromedriver_81.0.4044.69

  protractor:
    image: node:12.14
    container_name: protractor
    working_dir: /e2e/
    volumes:
      - .:/e2e
    ports:
    - "9229:9229"
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm i protractor && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update && ls -haltr && node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tags=@docker"
    depends_on:
    - selenium-hub
    - chrome

volumes:
  shared_repository:
```

When executing `docker-compose up` there is an error informing:

> [09:09:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver protractor
> | [09:09:18] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly... protractor
> | [09:09:18] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
> protractor      | [09:09:18] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server
> terminated early with status 127 protractor      |     at
> /e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52 protractor
> |     at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) protractor      | [09:09:18]
> E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Comment: any idea? I have not achieved to solve it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project has some misunderstanding points, but I think the main problem is you are using the local Webdriver instead of the Selenium Hub instance you are raising. I think we could simplify the docker-compose.yaml file to:

```
version: '2.4'
services:

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
    - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    container_name: chrome
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
    - "5900:5900"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=chromedriver_81.0.4044.69

  protractor:
    image: node:12.14
    container_name: protractor
    ports:
    - "9229:9229"
    command: bash -c "apt update && apt install -y git && git clone -b main https://github.com/AlfredoBazo/opwDocker.git && cd opwDocker && npm install && node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tags=@docker"
    depends_on:
    - selenium-hub
    - chrome
```

And you will need to modify your protractor.conf.js adding the line:

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub'
```

And removing the next one:

```
directConnect: true
```

Anyway, I will include some other changes that will be necessary to make it run in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/AlfredoBazo/opwDocker/pull/1)